# Push notification without opening app even once?

Tags: android, flutter

I have an app for device registration, I want users to register their device for warranty. App will be pre install by the OS and I want to send notification for the users who didn't register even if they did not open the app for once. But according to my knowledge it is necessary to open the app once to receive notifications.

Comment: "But according to my knowledge it is necessary to open the app once to receive notifications" -- if by "receive notifications" you mean "receive push messages from Firebase Cloud Messaging", then user-installed apps need to be opened before those will work. "App will be pre install by the OS" -- talk to the device manufacturer that is pre-installing your app and determine what your options are. The rules can be a bit different for pre-installed apps, but that largely is up to the manufacturer.

Comment: you can send notification from web server or simply you can use firebase cloud messeging